# UILabel and Text invisible after archive and upload to testflight

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, testflight, uialertviewcontroller

I have been stuck on a problem since last week. The thing is when I build on my phone/simulator, my app works well shows like the first picture with label and texts showing perfectly. But, when I archive and upload to testFlight or exports, it shows like the second picture(No visible Text/UILabel anywhere in the app).
Things I’ve tried:

1. custom font: I was able to override the systemfont successfully but still faced with the same problem after upload
2. accessibility inspector: I was able to read out the texts in the label meaning they are there but not showing.

This is the correct way for the app to show. The text and labels should be visible:

[image: This is the correct way for the app to show, the text and labels should be visible]

This is how it is showing when i upload and install from Testflight. All text and labels blank (even `UIAlertViewController`):

[image: This is how it is showing when i upload and install from testflight all text and labels blank (even UIAlertViewController)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible to have your dark mode on on the device you install the build? And maybe you used custom colors within the app so it only reflects in the text colors, which may be system.

E.g.: you used custom white for your background color (not system white) and the text was system black. After changing to dark mode, the text will turn white, but the background will stay white because it's custom

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I don't have a custom color and again i tested it on the device before uploading and it was perfect. the error is when i download it from testflight. i also used accessibility inspector and it verified the the text are there... i even inverted the view still the same error.